# Return something that's allocated on the stack

Tags: stack, rust, lifetime

I have the following simplified code, where a struct `A` contains a certain attribute. I'd like to create new instances of `A` from an existing version of that attribute, but how do I make the lifetime of the attribute's new value last past the function call?

```
pub struct A<'a> {
    some_attr: &'a str,
}

impl<'a> A<'a> {
    fn combine(orig: &'a str) -> A<'a> {
        let attr = &*(orig.to_string() + "suffix");
        A { some_attr: attr }
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", A::combine("blah").some_attr);
}
```

The above code produces

```
error[E0597]: borrowed value does not live long enough
 --> src/main.rs:7:22
  |
7 |         let attr = &*(orig.to_string() + "suffix");
  |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ does not live long enough
8 |         A { some_attr: attr }
9 |     }
  |     - temporary value only lives until here
  |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the impl at 5:1...
 --> src/main.rs:5:1
  |
5 | / impl<'a> A<'a> {
6 | |     fn combine(orig: &'a str) -> A<'a> {
7 | |         let attr = &*(orig.to_string() + "suffix");
8 | |         A { some_attr: attr }
9 | |     }
10| | }
  | |_^
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This question most certainly was answered before, but I'm not closing it as a duplicate because the code here is somewhat different and I think it is important.

Note how you defined your function:

```
fn combine(orig: &'a str) -> A<'a>
```

It says that it will return a value of type `A` whose insides live exactly as long as the provided string. However, the body of the function violates this declaration:

```
let attr = &*(orig.to_string() + "suffix");
A {
    some_attr: attr
}
```

Here you construct a *new* `String` obtained from `orig`, take a slice of it and try to return it inside `A`. However, the lifetime of the implicit variable created for `orig.to_string() + "suffix"` is strictly smaller than the lifetime of the input parameter. Therefore, your program is rejected.

Another, more practical way to look at this is consider that the string created by `to_string()` and concatenation has to live somewhere. However, you only return a borrowed slice of it. Thus when the function exits, the string is destroyed, and the returned slice becomes invalid. This is exactly the situation which Rust prevents.

To overcome this you can either store a `String` inside `A`:

```
pub struct A {
    some_attr: String
}
```

or you can use [`std::borrow::Cow`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html) to store either a slice or an owned string:

```
pub struct A<'a> {
    some_attr: Cow<'a, str>
}
```

In the last case your function could look like this:

```
fn combine(orig: &str) -> A<'static> {
    let attr = orig.to_owned() + "suffix";
    A {
        some_attr: attr.into()
    }
}
```

Note that because you construct the string inside the function, it is represented as an owned variant of `Cow` and so you can use `'static` lifetime parameter for the resulting value. Tying it to `orig` is also possible but there is no reason to do so.

With `Cow` it is also possible to create values of `A` directly out of slices without allocations:

```
fn new(orig: &str) -> A {
    A { some_attr: orig.into() }
}
```

Here the lifetime parameter of `A` will be tied (through lifetime elision) to the lifetime of the input string slice. In this case the borrowed variant of `Cow` is used, and no allocation is done.

Also note that it is better to use `to_owned()` or `into()` to convert string slices to `String`s because these methods do not require formatting code to run and so they are more efficient.

> how can you return an `A` of lifetime `'static` when you're creating it on the fly? Not sure what "owned variant of `Cow`" means and why that makes `'static` possible.

Here is the definition of `Cow`:

```
pub enum Cow<'a, B> where B: 'a + ToOwned + ?Sized {
    Borrowed(&'a B),
    Owned(B::Owned),
}
```

It looks complex but it is in fact simple. An instance of `Cow` may either contain a reference to some type `B` or an owned value which could be derived from `B` via the `ToOwned` trait. Because `str` implements `ToOwned` where `Owned` associated type equals to `String` (written as `ToOwned<Owned = String>`, when this enum is specialized for `str`, it looks like this:

```
pub enum Cow<'a, str> {
    Borrowed(&'a str),
    Owned(String)
}
```

Therefore, `Cow<str>` may represent either a string slice or an owned string - and while `Cow` does indeed provide methods for clone-on-write functionality, it is just as often used to hold a value which can be either borrowed or owned in order to avoid extra allocations. Because `Cow<'a, B>` implements `Deref<Target = B>`, you can get `&B` from `Cow<'a, B>` with simple reborrowing: if `x` is `Cow<str>`, then `&*x` is `&str`, regardless of what is contained inside of `x` - naturally, you can get a slice out of both variants of `Cow`.

You can see that the `Cow::Owned` variant does not contain any references inside it, only `String`. Therefore, when a value of `Cow` is created using `Owned` variant, *you* can choose any lifetime you want (remember, lifetime parameters are much like generic type parameters; in particular, it is the caller who gets to choose them) - there are no restrictions on it. So it makes sense to choose `'static` as the greatest lifetime possible.

> Does `orig.to_owned` remove ownership from whoever's calling this function? That sounds like it would be inconvenient.

The `to_owned()` method belongs to `ToOwned` trait:

```
pub trait ToOwned {
    type Owned: Borrow<Self>;
    fn to_owned(&self) -> Self::Owned;
}
```

This trait is implemented by `str` with `Owned` equal to `String`. `to_owned()` method returns an owned variant of whatever value it is called on. In this particular case, it creates a `String` out of `&str`, effectively copying contents of the string slice into a new allocation. Therefore no, `to_owned()` does not imply ownership transfer, it's more like it implies a "smart" clone.

> As far as I can tell String implements `Into<Vec<u8>>` but not `str`, so how can we call `into()` in the 2nd example?

The `Into` trait is very versatile and it is implemented for lots of types in the standard library. `Into` is usually implemented through the `From` trait: if `T: From<U>`, then `U: Into<T>`. There are two important implementations of `From` in the standard library:

```
impl<'a> From<&'a str> for Cow<'a, str>

impl<'a> From<String> for Cow<'a, str>
```

These implementations are very simple - they just return `Cow::Borrowed(value)` if `value` is `&str` and `Cow::Owned(value)` if `value` is `String`.

This means that `&'a str` and `String` implement `Into<Cow<'a, str>>`, and so they can be converted to `Cow` with `into()` method. That's exactly what happens in my example - I'm using `into()` to convert `String` or `&str` to `Cow<str>`. Without this explicit conversion you will get an error about mismatched types.

Comment: Thanks, it works! But there's a lot I don't understand here, how can you return an `A` of lifetime `static` when you're creating it on the fly? Not sure what "owned variant of `Cow`" means and why that makes `'static` possible. We're not ever modifying `some_attr` at any point -- isn't that usually the point of "copy on write", to allow for writes? Does `orig.to_owned` remove ownership from whoever's calling this function? That sounds like it would be inconvenient. As far as I can tell `String` implements `Into<Vec<u8>>` but not `str`, so how can we call `into()` in the 2nd example?

Comment: Whoa, that's a lot of questions! I've updated my answer, hopefully it would be helpful :)